# How do I create a rewrite rule only for certain requesting domains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using a rewrite rule in my HTACCESS file that directs all images to a PHP file.

```
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ adaptive-images.php
```

This HTACCESS file sits on a domain I use as a CDN for my other domains. I only want the rule to apply when the images is requested by an external domain.

How do I specify a rewrite condition that does this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I only want the rule to apply when the images are requested by an external domain.

You want to have a rewrite condition on the *http_referer*. Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !cdndomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ adaptive-images.php
```

and in case there is no *http_referer* because the URL was typed directly in the browser, but you want to serve the real images, you can use this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !cdndomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ adaptive-images.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^*.?yourdomain.com$
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ adaptive-images.php
```

Comment: Do you need to add more specific domains?

Comment: Or do you refer to control de user domain who asks for the image?